# Getting list of Categories for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm trying to generate a list of the categories of my custom post types ('products', and 'specialties'), and nothing will display. Does anyone know what's wrong with this code??

**EDIT:** 
The below code is now displaying a link, but will not take me to my custom post types of 'product'..it leads me to a "That page can't be found" page.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'products ); ?>">Products</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you edited your post, did you get it to work for that first part?

now for your edit, you need to give more context. I am able to get the archive link and content using that function. Most likely, you have another code or customization that is conflicting with this function in your setup.

I would check

- The post type has the `has_archive` args is set to `true`.
- Flush the rewrite rules to make sure they are clean.
- Look at the timing of your hook call to make sure it is called after your post type is setup